# Running bin/console returns ": No such file or directory"

Tags: bundler

I built a gem using "bundle gem gem_name" back on bundler 1.7.  I'm now using bundler 1.9.4.  I created a new gem using 1.9.4 and I noticed the gem template has changed around a bit.  I decided to go back to the old 1.7 gem and upgrade it to the new format;  I'm running into an error when running the new `bin/console` command.

I've updated the .gemspec file to:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'basic/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|

  ...other settings here...

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org by setting 'allowed_push_host', or
  # delete this section to allow pushing this gem to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata['allowed_push_host'] = "TODO: Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against public gem pushes."
  end

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.9"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

I've also created the `bin/console` file.

When I run `bin/console` from the command line, I get the following error

```
: No such file or directory
```

When I run bin/console in the gem that was generated using bundler 1.9.4, everything works fine.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out.  I created the bin/console file in Sublime Text on Windows. This resulted in Windows line endings being added to the file which made the file unexecuteable back in Linux.  Here's what I did to untangle things:

I opened bin/console in Vim to make sure the file saved out with Unix line endings:

```
vi bin/console
```

Then typed

```
:set fileformat=unix
```

Press return. Vim might not appear to do anything (i.e. `:set fileformat=unix"` might still appear on the line)

Next save and close the file by typing:

```
:wq!
```

Now bin/console should work.

I also changed Sublime Text to force it to use Unix line ending by default.  Click the `Preferences/Settings-User` menu option.  Add the following setting:

```
{
  "default_line_ending": "unix",
}
```

You could probably just open and save the file through Sublime Text after making the above change (if you use that editor), instead of going through Vim.